# Why does my ajax call fail when an almost identical one succeeds?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this HTML

```
<a href="/noJavascript" id="rejoinGroups">Rejoin</a>
<a href="/noJavascript" class="removeGroup" id="Testing">Remove</a>
```

and I am binding the links to a function using unobstrusive javascript like so:

```
$(function SetUp()
    {
    var el = document.getElementById('rejoinGroups');
    el.onclick = rejoinGroups;
    var removeElements = document.getElementsByClassName('removeGroup');
    for (var i = 0; i < removeElements.length; i++) {
        removeElements[i].onclick = function() {
            removeGroup(this.id);
        }
    }
  });
```

There may be many 'Remove' link generated hence why I am binding it differently, (but currently I have only one), and am passing the id as the function parameter.

These are the functions I am biding to.  **I have deliberately made them identical for testing as the first one (with the groupName parameter) doesn't work, but the second one does and I don't understand why.** Once this issue is fixed I'll actually use the `groupName` parameter.  The second returns a 200 code and the first immediately gives an 'Error0' message, then goes to the `/noJavascript` page.  I can only assume it's something to do with the parameter, but it seems to be set correctly, so I'm not sure what it is.  What am I missing?

```
function removeGroup(groupName){    
    $.ajax({
            url: '/tasks/aTask',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {userId:38},
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
            {         
               alert(jqXHR.status);                      
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
               alert("Error" + jqXHR.status);
            }
        });
        return false;        
}

function rejoinGroups(){
   $.ajax({
            url: '/tasks/aTask',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {userId:38},
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
            {         
               alert(jqXHR.status);                      
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
               alert("Error" + jqXHR.status);
            }
        });
        return false;
}
```

this is what I get in the chrome dev window for the second function:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8888/tasks/aTask
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:9
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie:dev_appserver_login=test@example.com:true:18580476422013912411; JSESSIONID=10yktze1j72fa
Host:localhost:8888
Origin:http://localhost:8888
Referer:http://localhost:8888/users/38
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.79 Safari/535.11
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Form Dataview URL encoded
userId:38
Response Headersview source
Content-Length:0
Server:Jetty(6.1.x)
```

and this is what I get for the first (failing) one:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8888/tasks/aTask
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Origin:http://localhost:8888
Referer:http://localhost:8888/users/38
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.79 Safari/535.11
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Form Dataview URL encoded
userId:38
```

Comment: Is this the real code?  The `groupName` parameter is passed but never used?

Comment: @JamesMontagne The 'real' code was failing and I couldn't figure out why, so I replaced it with some code that was working (that didn't use the parameter) to see if I could figure out why it was failing and that still failed, which made me think its something to do with the parameter or the binding.  So the real code will use the param, but if I can get this code above to work I think the real code should as well.  I've edited the question to make this clearer.

Comment: I was only asking because I see no way that these two identical functions have different results.  I figured there must be something missing which is causing the issue.

Comment: Maybe to do with something on your server? Are you using Firebug or similar to see the data being sent to the AJAX op, and see if any server errors occur when it is called?

Comment: @JamesMontagne you and me both :)

Comment: The odd thing is that the fact that it forwards to `/noJavascript` implies that it never hits the `return false`.  This would mean that `$.ajax` has an immediate error.  If that were the case, the ajax request should not have been sent.  But, since you get the alert with `Error 0` we know it did send... doesn't add up.

Comment: @JamesMontagne if I put a breakpoint on the `return false` it hits it, then forwards to `/noJavascript`... don't make sense...

Comment: The fact that it forwards makes sense: the named function returns false but the anonymous one doesn't.

Comment: @Rick I think that's it!  I changed the anonymous function to call `rejoinGroups()` instead and it still failed, changed it to be `return rejoinGroups()` and it works the same as the other one.  And now I've changed it to `return removeGroup(this.id);` it still works.

Comment: @Sam Really? I guess the Ajax must have been working all along then, but unnoticed since the page was forwarding? I'll edit my answer shortly (my old one was way off, lol)

Comment: @Rick already edited it for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not very sure, but I think it might be because your anonymous function is not returning the result of the function. Try changing:

```
removeGroup(this.id);
```

to

```
return removeGroup(this.id);
```

Comment: This would introduce a closures-inside-for-loops bug

Comment: But the passed parameter is never used.

Comment: I was just thinking perhaps the script was dying before even getting to the function, so the passed parameter wouldn't matter. But clearly, due to the edits in the question, that's not what's happening.

Comment: @Rick I edited the answer so I could accept it for you.  thanks.